# Await operator, executin until Task returned

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

Suppose, we have the code to calculate Factorial of a number.

```
public Task<long> FactorialAsync(int n) 
{
     long result = 1;
     for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
          result *= i;
     return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

and some code that uses **FactorialAsync()**

```
public async Task CalculateFactorial(int n)
{
    long result = await FactorialAsync(n);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

What bothers me is that when code reaches await FactorialAsync(n) it will launch the task and will wait until Task is returned to analyze it. So until code reaches inside of **FactorialAsync(n)** to the line: 
**return Task.FromResult(result)** it will be executing synchronously. Am I correct??

Comment: What happens when you run the code?  Does it in fact run synchronously, or does it not?

Comment: Not following.  Because you marked `CalculateFactorial` as `async`, the compiler built up a little state machine inside your `CalculateFactorial` method.  Assuming you are working in a program that supports asynchrony (as most things other than console apps do), then when `await FactorialAsync` executes, the state machine will fire off `FactorialAsync` and step away from the current execution context.  When the task completes (`return Task.FromResult`), the state machine gets told, "hey, I'm finished", and control is returned, executing the `WriteLine` statement.

Comment: Yes, but await operator needs instance of Task. The instance of Task is returned at the end of the method FactorialAsync() .. So I thought that while the Task is not returned to the caller it will continue executing synchronously. Or maybe await operator is not waiting for Task and just fires it off

Comment: OK, after your edit, your question makes sense.  Yes, `FactorialAsync` executes synchronously (it has to), and `CalculateFactorial` will not execute any more of your code until the Task completes.  However, during that time, a little state machine the compiler sets up within `async` methods allows your code to step away from the current execution context.  For example, if you were running on the UI thread in a WinForms app, your `FactorialAsync` would not block that thread while `CalculateFactorial` was running.

Comment: @NickReshetinsky You have a hypothesis of what's happening.  That's good.  Now run the program, and test that hypothesis.  If it behaves in the way you've predicted, it's a good indication that your hypothesis has merit.  If it doesn't, then it means your hypothesis is incorrect or incomplete.

Comment: @Flydog57 The question hasn't been edited.  Also, you might want to try running the code too, to see how it behaves, to verify your own assertions about how it will behave.

Comment: OK, I will try now

Comment: OK, end of the day.  The first read made little sense.  The second read did.  I figured it was the author's doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  You may have an incorrect understanding of what `await` does. **Await does not make a method asynchronous**.  Await *asynchronously waits* for the result of an asynchronous method.  **The method has to already be asynchronous.**

If you call a synchronous method that returns a task, then the synchronous method runs until it returns the task.  That's normal and expected.

Put another way: an asynchronous method runs until the first `await` of an incomplete task, at which point it returns a task.  **Your method has no awaits**.  Therefore it is not asynchronous. All you've done is packaged up the answer in a task, and then extracted it.  If you want code to be asynchronous, you have to actually do *something* to make it asynchronous.

Comment: I understand in the following way - await operator just waits for Task instance, if the method returns Task instance AT ONCE like Task.Run() then the calling code will return back until Task is completed. But when Task instance is not returned AT ONCE, it will execute SYNCHRONOUSLY UNTIL IT GETS INSTANCE OF TASK

Comment: @NickReshetinsky: await first *obtains the task*, so the method runs until it returns a task. Then it checks to see if the task is complete; if it is, then the program continues synchronously. If the task is incomplete, then the await signs up the current method as the continuation of the task, and returns a different task to the caller of the current method.

Comment: Thanks, same thought

Comment: Yes, I know I could use Task.Run() inside of method FactorialAsync() to make it asynchronous. I just wondered for this case. When the method has Task instance returned at the end of method